# BottomSheetDialogFragment setting peek hight and other behaviors

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

I want the bottom screen to peek and then take up the full screen when slid up. currently, I have it showing when I press "Button 1" because I cannot get the peek to work.

[image]

I can, however, slide it up so that it takes up the full screen. Ideally, it would do this automatically.

[image]

When I slide it back down, it goes down all the way.

[image]

I want the following behavior:

1. The Bottom Sheet should peek `300dp` or whatever, at all times.
2. Sliding up on the Bottom Sheet should result in it taking up the full screen view, like in the second picture.
3. Sliding down the Bottom Sheet should go back to its peek height.

I don't know how to control the Bottom Sheet behavior because, the `BottomSheetBehavior`class only seems to work for the ones defined in XML.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

            // ... 
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_bottom_sheet.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Some text..."
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.qqq.bottomsheets;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
    private TestBottomSheetDialogFragment mTestBottomSheetDialogFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_1 );
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_2 );
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_3 );

        mTestBottomSheetDialogFragment = new TestBottomSheetDialogFragment();

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_1: {
                mTestBottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), mTestBottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TestBottomSheetDialogFragment.java**

```
package com.example.qqq.bottomsheets;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TestBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you found solution for this case?